# Separate value after certain character by space in Swift

Tags: regex, swift

hi i have a value which is

> Blockquote
>   1 1:0.0644343 1 1:0.0309334 1 1:0.0261616 
>   Blockquote

i want to separate value by space but after certain character to get result like this..is there any possible solution . i know we can do in regex

> Blockquote
>   "1 1:0.0644343" 
>   "1 1:0.0309334" 
>   "1 1:0.0261616"
>   Blockquote

Comment: Because not all spaces create a separation, you're talking about a lexical analyzer (or, God forbid, a parser) of some sort. In that case, why not regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think regex is the perfect tool here:

```
var str = "Blockquote 1 1:0.0644343 1 1:0.0309334 1 1:0.0261616 Blockquote"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\d \\d:[\\.0-9]+)", options: [])
let matches = regex.matchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count))

for m in matches.reverse() {
    let range = m.rangeAtIndex(1)
    let startIndex = str.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location)
    let endindex = startIndex.advancedBy(range.length)
    let value = str[startIndex..<endindex]

    str.replaceRange(startIndex..<endindex, with: "\"\(str[startIndex..<endindex])\"")
}

print(str)
```